# retrieving data from database by id and name

Tags: php, mysql, domdocument

I am trying to get some data from my database to put it on my website.
My database has the following rows: id, type(titel,image,paragraph),pagename and the content(for an example if you choose titel as type you put html code in there to show a h1).
I have tried something but that did not work. Can you guys help me out?
My code :

```
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
$select_data = mysql_select_db('portfolio', $connect);
$select_data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM page_directory WHERE pagename='index' id='1'") or die(mysql_error());
while($fetch=mysql_fetch_assoc($select_data)) {

    $oDiv = $dom->getElementById('contentContainer');
    $oH1 = $dom->createElement('h1',$fetch["content"]);

    $oDiv->appendChild($oH1);
}
```

Comment: I think you missed `AND` between `pagename='index' id='1'` in your query.

Comment: Yep thats it! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

**CODE**

```
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
$select_data = mysql_select_db('portfolio', $connect);
$select_data = mysql_query(
  "SELECT * 
  FROM page_directory 
  WHERE pagename='index' 
  AND id='1'") or die(mysql_error());
while($fetch=mysql_fetch_assoc($select_data)) {
$oDiv = $dom->getElementById('contentContainer');
$oH1 = $dom->createElement('h1',$fetch["content"]);

$oDiv->appendChild($oH1);
}
```